# IOS app different when loading via TestFlight

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store-connect, xcode8, itunes-app

I have a view in storyboard controller which extends my custom UIView and when I try to draw a gradient in drawRect it displays fine when loading on to device/sim via XCode but when I install via TestFlight after uploading to ITunes Connect the gradient isn't present at first (displays black background) - it needs a rotation of the device and the gradient displays fine again. What could be causing this behaviour?

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

NSArray *gradientColors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                           (id)[[self colorWithHexString:@"FF7542"]CGColor],
                           (id)[[self colorWithHexString:@"FF7542"]CGColor],
                           (id)[[self colorWithHexString:@"FFC0A1"]CGColor],
                           nil];


CGFloat gradientLocations[] = {0, 1};
CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace, (__bridge CFArrayRef) gradientColors, gradientLocations);

CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect));
CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect));

CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, startPoint, endPoint, 0);
CGGradientRelease(gradient);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

NSShadow *shadow = [[NSShadow alloc] init];
[shadow setShadowColor : BLACK_SHADOW];
[shadow setShadowOffset : CGSizeMake (1.0, 1.0)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by creating my gradient another way and strangely it shows first time when loaded without the need for a rotation.

```
CGContextRef current_context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSaveGState(current_context);

// Gradient
CGFloat locations[2] = {0.0, 1.0};
CGFloat components[8] = {1.00,0.75,0.63,1.0,1.00,0.46,0.26,1.0};
CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(colorspace, components, locations, 2);
CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect));
CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect));
CGContextDrawLinearGradient(current_context, gradient, startPoint, endPoint, 0);
CGGradientRelease(gradient);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorspace);
```